# Where does Polymer 2 CLI store variants?

Tags: polymer, polymer-2.x, polymer-cli

When you have a Polymer 2 `bower.json` with dependency variants and run `polymer install --variants`, where does it store the variant dependent components?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The variants are stored in the same parent directory of the default `bower_components/`. For example, given variants named "`variant-1`" and "`variant-2`", the resulting directory structure of the command is:

```
bower-variant-1.json
bower-variant-2.json
bower.json
bower_components/
bower_components-variant-1/
bower_components-variant-2/
```

*You can find an example test fixture for the `polymer install --variants` command in [`polymer-cli` source](https://github.com/Polymer/polymer-cli/tree/444d955/src/test/integration/fixtures/install-variants). Run the command in that directory to see the result described above.*